# Sideloading belongsTo data in Ember.js RC1 with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Sideloading is working in our app for hasMany relationships, but I can't get it to work for belongsTo relationships. I'm trying to use the documented `DS.RESTAdapter.configure()` method, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. The error I am getting is `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key occasions but you have no mapping for it`.

Note that we don't need to specify the `hasMany` sideload mappings, as that request just works. `App.Occasion.find();` works fine. `App.Reminder.find();` throws the error.

Models

```
App.Reminder = DS.Model.extend(
  occasion: DS.belongsTo('App.Occasion')
  ...
)
App.Occasion = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations,
  reminders: DS.hasMany('App.Reminder')
  ...
)
```

Store.js.coffee

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure('App.Occasion',
    sideLoadAs: 'occasions'
)
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  revision: 11
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
)
```

JSON (for occasions)

```
{
  reminders: [{},...],
  occasions: [{reminders: [1,2,...]},...]
}
```

JSON (for reminders)

```
{
  reminders: [{occasion_id: 1},...],
  occasions: [{},...]
}
```

Comment: As a workaround, I am sideloading `hasMany` relationships and embedding the `belongsTo` relationships. Our app has two main screens that offer different views of the data, so this shouldn't be too much of a performance hit until I find the real solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `sideloadAs` instead of `sideLoadAs` (not capital `L`)